# Sync a single file instead of the whole library of the whole folder inside one drive desktop app

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sync, onedrive

I know that i can sync a whole SharePoint library or the whole folder with one drive application. as follow, by going to a single folder or to the root folder and click on Sync:-

[image]

but can i do this for a single file? i do not want all the files and folders to be synced to my one drive i want the user to select a single file and sync it.. can we do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sync functionality applies to a library, not a single file. However, this does not mean that you need to keep all of the library's files offline. You can instead choose which file you want to keep offline after you have synced the library.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. but how i can specify that i only need one file to be synced?